# Drupal Commerce Custom Search Form

Tags: theming, commerce

I'm creating a site based on Commerce Kickstart.k My client wants a search form on the front page. The form will have multiple fields on it, some of which are bracketing parameters -- i.e., the price is less than $100 but more than $50. He wants using this form to result in being routed to a search page. IOW, the user fills out the form, clicks on a 'Search' button, and the browser replaces the front page with a results page. (In my mind, ideally, a faceted search page).

I've tried to implement this using Views exposed filters, but the view always presents the unfiltered data along with the input fields, and whether it's a block or page, does not offer the results on a separate page.

I've tried to find a module to help, and looked at Custom Search, but it requires that Drupal's standard search module be turned on, which it is not (by default) in Commerce Kickstart. Commmerce Kickstart uses the Search API and a bunch of custom modules to deliver a database-indexed search. I don't want to interfere with Kickstart's already complex series of search modules, plus the use of the standard search is an indicator I would not get what I want from this solution.

I found no hooks or examples of hooks that let me do this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you for your help.

--Marshall

Comment: You can make exposed filters "required" to show no results by default. You may also be interested in configuring the "exposed filters as a block" then can show the filter form on the homepage, and redirect to search results.

Comment: excelente this was aseful for me too

Comment: How to redirect to search results from a block?